# C bitmap: rotation and zoom

Tags: c, bitmap, rotation, zooming

I'm recently checking out C for a friend having problems with it for school. As I only have learned java and C#, though it would be easy. But currently stuck on this.

I have a project reading a small bmp (512x512) image. I've managed to change some colors on it and have it rotated (both horizontal as vertical). Though I'm stuck with the -90° rotation.

**1. ROTATION (512x512)**

Currently I have this code (both getPixel and setPixel are my own functions):

```
typedef struct _bitmap {
    char file_path[PATH_MAX+1];
    char magic_number[3];
    unsigned int size;
    unsigned char application[5];
    unsigned int start_offset;
    unsigned int bitmapHeaderSize;
    unsigned int width;
    unsigned int height;
    unsigned short int depth;
    unsigned  char* header;
    PIXEL* raster;
} BITMAP;

void rotate(BITMAP* bmp) {
    int i;
    int j;
    PIXEL* originalPixel;
    BITMAP* originalBmp;

    deepCopyBitmap(bmp, originalBmp);

    for(j=1; j <= bmp->height; j++) {
        for(i=1; i <= bmp->width; i++) {
            originalPixel=getPixel(originalBmp->raster, bmp->width, bmp->height, j, i);
            setPixel(bmp->raster, bmp->width, bmp->height, (bmp->width + 1 - i), j, originalPixel);
        }
    }                  
}

void deepCopyBitmap(BITMAP* bmp, BITMAP* copy) {
    *copy = *bmp;
    if (copy->raster) {
        copy->raster = malloc(copy->height * sizeof(*copy->raster));
        for (int i = 0; i < copy->height; i++) {
            copy->raster[i] = malloc(copy->width * sizeof(*copy->raster[i]));
            memcpy(copy->raster[i], bmp->raster[i], copy->width * sizeof(*copy->raster[i]));
        }
    }
}

indirection requires pointer operand ('PIXEL' (aka 'struct _pixel') invalid)
            copy->raster[i] = malloc(copy->width * sizeof(*copy->raster[i]));
                                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
indirection requires pointer operand ('PIXEL' (aka 'struct _pixel') invalid)
            memcpy(copy->raster[i], bmp->raster[i], copy->width * sizeof(*copy->raster[i]));
                                                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
expanded from macro 'memcpy' __builtin___memcpy_chk (dest, src, len, __darwin_obsz0 (dest))
```

This correctly rotates the first diagonal part of the image, but the second part is totally wrong (having two times a part of the first diagonal).

I think the problem is, swapping pixels around and halfway I'm starting to swap already swapped pixels. So I tried to duplicate my bmp, to a original bitmap (originalBmp) and one rotated (rotatedBmp). Though I think it just copies the reference. **Anyone has an idea how I create a duplicate bmp?**

[As example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8k6tz.png) (sorry for the flue img): I want the vertical lines (left), to turn -90deg, so it becomes horizontal lines (right). Though the left diagonal part is correct. But the right part of the diagonal is incorrect copying a piece of the left diagonal. I think because it swaps pixels that are already swapped in the bmp file.

**2. ROTATION (512x1024)**

What happens if the height or width is the double of the other? Anyone knows how to start on this?

**3. ZOOM (200%)**

Anyone know how to do this? Get the center pixels of the bitmap, and make them twice at the start of the image, or is there a better/cleaner solution?

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8     3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6
2 2 3 4 5 6 7 8     3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6
3 3 3 4 5 6 7 8     4 4 4 4 5 5 6 6
4 4 4 4 5 6 7 8     4 4 4 4 5 5 6 6
5 5 5 5 5 6 7 8     5 5 5 5 5 5 6 6
6 6 6 6 6 6 7 8     5 5 5 5 5 5 6 6
7 7 7 7 7 7 7 8     6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6
8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8     6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6
```

Comment: Zoom by 200% == double every pixel in both directions, so each becomes four. Depends on the implementation if you want the result to be bigger or just a cropped part. Not rectangle, depends on the implementation again.

Comment: I don't know the `setPixel` and `getPixel` functions but I seems strange that the indexes (`i` and `j`) start from 1. Is that on purpose? In C you would normally start from 0.

Comment: Did you run the code using a debugger, stepping through it inspecting all relevant variables?

Comment: "*... only have learned java and C#, though it would be easy*" obviously not ... ;-) C is much more "low-level" then Java or C#. You want to learn about arrays, pointers and their relation, as well as about dynamic memory management using `malloc()`/`calloc()` and `free()`.

Answer (score 1):

From your code it seems clear that both `originalBmp`and `bmp` are pointers to some BMP-type. So when you do `originalBmp=bmp;`, you just get two pointers pointing to the same BMP, i.e. they operate on the same data.

I assume you have something like

```
struct BMP
{
   // ....
};
```

If that is the case you can make a copy like this:

```
struct BMP originalBmp = *bmp;
```

When using `originalBmp` you must use the `.` notation, e.g. `originalBmp.raster`

**EDIT An alternative approach**

Instead of making a copy of the original bmp you could do the rotation directly on the original. Each rotation will involve 4 locations. You can copy the 4 locations into temp variables first and then write them to their final location.

For a simple matrix it could be something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define WIDTH 4

// display function
void d(int t[WIDTH][WIDTH])
{
    int i, j;
    for (i=0; i<WIDTH;i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<WIDTH; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", t[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int org[WIDTH][WIDTH];
    int i, j;

    // Just initialize the matrix
    for (i=0; i<WIDTH;i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<WIDTH; j++)
        {
            org[i][j] = 10 + i*5 + j;
        }
    }

    printf("Original\n");
    d(org);

    // Rotate the matrix
    for (j=0; j < (WIDTH/2); j++)
    {
        for (i=0; i < ((WIDTH+1)/2); i++)
        {
            int t1 = org[j][i];
            int t2 = org[i][WIDTH-1-j];
            int t3 = org[WIDTH-1-j][WIDTH-1-i];
            int t4 = org[WIDTH-1-i][j];

            org[j][i] = t2;
            org[i][WIDTH-1-j] = t3;
            org[WIDTH-1-j][WIDTH-1-i] = t4;
            org[WIDTH-1-i][j] = t1;
        }
    }
    printf("Rotated\n");
    d(org);
    return 0;
}
```

This will output:

```
Original
10 11 12 13 
15 16 17 18 
20 21 22 23 
25 26 27 28 
Rotated
13 18 23 28 
12 17 22 27 
11 16 21 26 
10 15 20 25
```

Change to `#define WIDTH 5` and it will output:

```
Original
10 11 12 13 14 
15 16 17 18 19 
20 21 22 23 24 
25 26 27 28 29 
30 31 32 33 34 
Rotated
14 19 24 29 34 
13 18 23 28 33 
12 17 22 27 32 
11 16 21 26 31 
10 15 20 25 30
```

Comment: I've updated my code example.
Tried your solution and also give some more details regarding the function.
Though the result is still the same, I don't think that it "duplicates" the data in originalBmp/rotatedBmp.

Comment: @PeterVanGorp - you probably should show how the `BITMAP` looks. If it uses dynamic allocation, you'll need to do a deep-copy.

Comment: I've added the BITMAP

Comment: @PeterVanGorp - `BITMAP` has a pointer, i.e. `PIXEL* raster;` I guess this is where the 512x512 pixels are saved. Since it has a pointer, you'll have to do a deep-copy. In other words, you need to allocate space for a new `PIXEL` and then copy `PIXEL` from one `BITMAP` to the other.

Comment: @PeterVanGorp - see updated answer for an alternative approach

Comment: I'm trying your deep-copy (deepCopyBitmap). Though I have the following errors (see underneath the function).